# Handling time zone offset transition and daylight savings time with Joda

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime, timezone-offset

I am trying to parse datetime strings and create Joda DateTime objects.

My data comes from a legacy database that stores datetime strings without specifying the timezone/offset.  Although the timezone/offset of the datetime strings is not stored it is a business rule of the legacy system that all datetimes are stored in Eastern Time. Unfortunately I do not have the authority to update the way in which the legacy DB stores datetime strings.

Thus, I parse the datetime strings using JODA's "US/Eastern" time zone.

This approach throws an illegalInstance exception when the dateTime string falls within the hour that "disappears" when daylight savings is switched on.

I've created the following example code to demonstrate this behaviour and to show my proposed workaround.

```
public class FooBar {
public static final DateTimeZone EST = DateTimeZone.forID("EST");
public static final DateTimeZone EASTERN = DateTimeZone.forID("US/Eastern");

public static final DateTimeFormatter EST_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").withZone(EST);
public static final DateTimeFormatter EASTERN_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").withZone(EASTERN);


public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] listOfDateTimeStrings = {"2014-03-09 02:00:00.000", "2014-03-08 02:00:00.000"}; 

    System.out.println(" *********** 1st attempt  *********** ");
    for (String dateTimeString: listOfDateTimeStrings){
        try{
            final DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateTimeString, EASTERN_FORMATTER);
            System.out.println(dateTime);       
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(" *********** 2nd attempt  *********** ");
    for (String dateTimeString: listOfDateTimeStrings){
        try{
            final DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateTimeString, EST_FORMATTER);
            System.out.println(dateTime);       
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(" *********** 3rd attempt  *********** ");
    for (String dateTimeString: listOfDateTimeStrings){
        try{
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateTimeString, EST_FORMATTER);
            dateTime = dateTime.withZone(EASTERN);
            System.out.println(dateTime);       
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }       

}
```

}

Output produced:

```
 *********** 1st attempt  *********** 
Cannot parse "2014-03-09 02:00:00.000": Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (America/New_York)
2014-03-08T02:00:00.000-05:00
 *********** 2nd attempt  *********** 
2014-03-09T02:00:00.000-05:00
2014-03-08T02:00:00.000-05:00
 *********** 3rd attempt  *********** 
2014-03-09T03:00:00.000-04:00
2014-03-08T02:00:00.000-05:00
```

In the "3rd attempt" I get the expected result: the first datetime has an offset of -04:00. as it falls within the first hour of DST for 2015. The second timestamp has an offset of -05:00 as it falls outside of DST.

Is is safe to do this:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateTimeString, A_FORMATTER_WITH_TIME_ZONE_A);
dateTime = dateTime.withZone(TIME_ZONE_B);
```

I've tested this code with a few different combinations of datetime strings and time zones (and so far it works for all the test cases), but I was wondering if anyone with more Joda experience can see anything wrong/dangerous in this approach.

Or alternatively: is there a better way of doing handling the time zone offset transition with Joda?

Comment: +1 Nicely written question, with one minor exception: _"Is the code ... safe to use?"_  What do you mean by "safe"?  If you test it with sufficient edge cases, does it produce the expected and desired behavior?  You'll have to describe in more detail what you're asking specifically.

Comment: @JimGarrison thanks for pointers; I've updated the end of the question, hopefully it's more specific now.

Comment: When you say "all datetimes are stored in EST", do you literally mean that they are all stored in UTC-5 - Eastern *Standard* Time, or do you mean that they are stored in Eastern Time, which is UTC-5 (EST) for part of the year and UTC-4 (EDT) for the other part?  Because you also said, "when daylight savings is switched on in the EST timezone", I'm thinking you mean "Eastern Time", not "EST".  (Daylight saving *does not apply* during standard time.)

Comment: @MattJohnson You are correct, I meant to say "all datetimes are stored in Eastern Time".  I've edited the question. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful. The behaviour of the method [withZone(...)](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-) is documented as follows:

> Returns a copy of this datetime with a different time zone, preserving
>   the millisecond instant.

Keeping this in mind, you have to understand that EST and "America/New_York" (better than the outdated id "US/Eastern") are not the same. First one (EST) has fixed offset (no DST), but second one has DST including possible gaps. You should only apply EST as replacement for Eastern if you are sure that

a) you are already in the exception mode (normally parsed datetimes in Eastern zone should be accepted without repeated parsing otherwise applying EST would falsify the parsed instant),

b) you understand choosing EST in second (and third) try is choosing the instant after DST transition.

Regarding this limitations/constraints, your workaround will work (but only for the special pair EST versus America/New_York). Personally I find it frightening to use exception-based logic to workaround a severe limitation of Joda-Time. As counter example, the new JSR-310 does not use the exception strategy when handling gaps but the strategy to choose the later instant after gap pushed forward by the size of the gap (like the old `java.util.Calendar`-stuff).

I recommend you to first follow the advise of @Jim Garrison to look if the crapped data can be corrected before you apply such a workaround (my upvote for his answer).

**Update after reading your original spec requirement (obsolete - see below):**

If the spec of the legacy system says that **all times are stored in EST**, then you should parse it this way and NOT use "America/New_York" for parsing at all. Instead you can convert the parsed EST-instants to New-York-time in second phase (using `withZone(EASTERN)`. This way you will not have any exception logic because a (parsed) instant can always be converted to a local time representation in an unambigous way (the parsed instant of type `DateTime`, the converted result contains a local time). Code example:

```
public static final DateTimeZone EST = DateTimeZone.forID("EST");
public static final DateTimeZone EASTERN = DateTimeZone.forID("US/Eastern");
public static final DateTimeFormatter EST_FORMATTER = 
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").withZone(EST);

// in your parsing method...
String input = "2014-03-09 02:00:00.000";
DateTime dt = EST_FORMATTER.parseDateTime(input);
System.out.println(dt); // 2014-03-09T02:00:00.000-05:00
System.out.println(dt.withZone(EASTERN)); // 2014-03-09T03:00:00.000-04:00
```

**Update after comment and clarification of OP:**

Now it is confirmed that **the legacy system does not store timestamps in EST (with fixed offset UTC-05 but in EASTERN zone** ("America/New_York" with variable offset of either EST or EDT). First action should be to contact the supplier of invalid timestamps in order to see if they can correct the data. Else you can use following workaround:

Regarding the fact that your input contains timestamps without any offset or zone information I recommend first to parse as `LocalDateTime`.

=> static initialization part

```
// Joda-Time cannot parse "EDT" so we use hard-coded offsets
public static final DateTimeZone EST = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(-5);
public static final DateTimeZone EDT = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(-4);

public static final DateTimeZone EASTERN = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
public static final org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = 
    org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

=> in your parse method

```
String input = "2014-03-09 02:00:00.000";
LocalDateTime ldt = FORMATTER.parseLocalDateTime(input); // always working
System.out.println(ldt); // 2014-03-09T02:00:00.000
DateTime result;

try {
    result = ldt.toDateTime(EASTERN);
} catch (IllegalInstantException ex) {
    result = ldt.plusHours(1).toDateTime(EDT); // simulates a PUSH-FORWARD-strategy at gap
    // result = ldt.toDateTime(EST); // the same instant but finally display with EST offset
}
System.out.println(result); // 2014-03-09T03:00:00.000-04:00
// if you had chosen <<<ldt.toDateTime(EST)>>> then: 2014-03-09T02:00:00.000-05:00
```

**Another clarification due to last comment of OP:**

The method [toDateTime(DateTimeZone)](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#toDateTime-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-) producing a `DateTime` is documented as follows:

> In a daylight saving overlap, when the same local time occurs twice,
>   this method returns the first occurrence of the local time.

In other words, it chooses the earlier offset in case of overlap (in autumn). So there is no need to call

```
result = ldt.toDateTime(EASTERN).withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap();
```

However, it does not do any harm here, and you might prefer it for sake of documentation. On the other side: It does not make any sense to call in the exception handling (for gaps)

```
result = ldt.toDateTime(EDT).withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap();
```

because EDT (and EST, too) is a fixed offset where overlaps can never occur. So here the method `withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap()` does not do anything. Furthermore: Leaving out the correction `ldt.plusHours(1)` in case of EDT is not okay and will yield another instant. Already tested by me before writing this extra explanation, but of course, you can use the alternative `ldt.toDateTime(EST)` to achieve what you want (EDT != EST, but with the correction of `plusHours(1)` you get same instants). I have just noticed the EDT example to demonstrate how you can exactly model the standard JDK-behaviour. It is up to you which offset you prefer in case of resolving gaps (EDT or EST) but getting the same instants is vital here (`ldt.plusHours(1).toDateTime(EDT)` versus `result = ldt.toDateTime(EST)`).

Comment: While `EST` technical means UTC-5, it's not clear that the OP understands that. It's possible he indeed means the data is stored in "Eastern Time", inclusive of EST and EDT.  It would be good to get clarification.

Comment: In other words, while it makes sense for `2014-03-09T02:00:00.000` to be converted as `2014-03-09T03:00:00.000-04:00`, it's unlikely that other *valid* timestamps would intend to be shifted.  It would be odd if `2014-07-01T00:00:00.000` came through as `2014-07-01T01:00:00.000-04:00`.

Comment: FYI, I believe the correct solution would involve parsing the string to a `LocalDateTime` (using `parseLocalDateTime` on the formatter I think), then separately converting it to a `DateTime` in the `America/New_York` (or `US/Eastern` if you prefer) time zone.  However I can't recall how you tell Joda not to throw an exception during the conversion for values in the gap.  (I know it has `withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap` for the fall, but I'm not sure what it can do in the spring.)  (Feel free to steal any of this for an update)  Cheers!

Comment: @MattJohnson Good point, I am also not sure if the OP understands the difference between EST and America/New_York. Let's see. About `LocalDateTime`, this corresponds to the content of the input but can finally not avoid exceptions when converted to instant (here of type `DateTime`) using Easter zone around DST gaps. Joda-Time does not offer a smooth transition strategy. Other libs like Noda-Time have more to offer here (ZoneLocalMapping) or my lib Time4J, too. About other valid timestamps in summer, well, we don't know if the legacy system uses EST instead of UTC (strange but possible).

Comment: @MenoHochschild I wasn't clear on the difference between EST and Eastern time. I can now confirm that the legacy system I'm working with stores everything in Eastern time. 
Thanks for the input, it looks like your suggested solution is identical to the "third attempt" code in the OP. 
Is this assumption correct?

Comment: @YB-Abeokuta Thanks for clarification. I have now updated my answer. Sorry for exception-based logic which can only be avoided if you are ready to choose other libraries (for example the built-in time library in JDK).

Comment: @MenoHochschild Good solution, I have finally settled on your solution with a one line change. Instead of: 
`result = ldt.plusHours(1).toDateTime(EDT); `
I'm using:
`result = ldt.toDateTime(EDT).withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap();`

MattJohnson thanks for the nudge towards `withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap`.

I've tested this with spring and autumn DST change dates and it gives the expected results.
If you update this post to use `withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap` I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @YB-Abeokuta Please see my update in the answer. It is different from what you expected or asked me to do but I hope it is now clearer.

Comment: @MenoHochschild makes sense. Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your question boils down to

> I have to cope with timestamp values that are not technically valid and interpret them consistently

What you do with them depends totally on your requirements.  If you are writing the software for an employer, the owner of the project must be the one to make that decision.  You as the developer do not yet have the authority to decide what to do with invalid input if that hasn't been specified by the designer/architect.

I suggest you go back to the project owner/manager, inform them of the problem (input contains date/time stamps that don't actually exist) and get them to make the decision on how to handle them.

Comment: This is the most correct answer. I can't accept it, though. Unfortunately I need to find a workaround that can interpret the invalid values as my PO has no desire to take on the monumental task of fixing the root issue.

Comment: I didn't say they have to fix the root issue, just decide on the rules used to interpret the invalid time stamps in the code you're writing. This happens a lot when dealing with legacy systems. No decision will be perfect, but the critical task is to document what you decide. Future developers will thank you for identifying the problem and establishing how to deal with it.